# Why does the interface for auto_ptr specify two copy-constructor-like constructors

Tags: c++, stl, auto-ptr

I was going through the auto_ptr documentation on this link [auto_ptr](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/sourcepro/edition9/html/stdlibref/auto-ptr.html)
There is something which i could not fully understand why is it done. In the interface section there are two declarations for its copy constructor

1)

```
auto_ptr(auto_ptr<X>&) throw ();
```

2)

```
template <class Y> 
     auto_ptr(auto_ptr<Y>&) throw();
```

What purpose is this for.

Comment: The title of this question should be changed to "Why does the interface for auto_ptr specify two copy-constructor-like constructors?"

Comment: done , i was confused when i saw this interface and couldnt think of a good title :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there in case you can implicitly convert the pointers:

```
struct base {};
struct derived : base {};

std::auto_ptr<derived> d(new derived);
std::auto_ptr<base> b(d); // converts
```

Also, you didn't ask but you'll notice the copy-constructor is non-const. This is because the `auto_ptr` will take ownership of the pointer. In the sample above, after `b` is constructed, `d` holds on to nothing. This makes `auto_ptr` unsuitable for use in containers, because it can't be copied around.

C++0x ditches `auto_ptr` and makes one called `unique_ptr`. This pointer has the same goals, but accomplishes them correctly because of move-semantics. That is, while it cannot be copied, it can "move" ownership:

```
std::unique_ptr<derived> d(new derived);

std::unique_ptr<base> b(d); // nope, cannot be copied
std::unique_ptr<base> b(std::move(d)); // but can be moved
```

This makes `unique_ptr` suitable for use in containers, because they no longer copy their values, they move them.

Comment: Specifically, the *second* constructor is there for implicit conversion (which technically makes it not a copy constructor).

Comment: The first _is_ a valid copy constructor. A copy constructor can take either a reference or a const reference to the class type. Either form is a valid copy constructor.

Comment: @Charles: Ah, I always thought it had to be a `const&`, my mistake.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, it's valid as a copy constructor, technically.  But it's quite surprising for something called a 'copy constructor' to modify the thing being copied.  It's not really a copy constructor IMHO if that's what it's doing.  It's all you __can__ do in non-C++0x C++ though.

Comment: just wanted to validate one thing - since const is not being use in auto_ptr(auto_ptr<X>&), this is what lead to compilation errors when a non const auto_ptr is added to a container like vector

Comment: @Yogesh: Correct. The parameter to, say, `push_back` is a `const&`. So it cannot be modified, against the wishes of the constructor provided by `auto_ptr`.

Comment: @Yogesh: Indeed. While it's still useful in some situations, it's definitely a dumber smart pointer. C++0x's `unique_ptr`, which can handle normal types as well as arrays, will definitely be a usable smart pointer.

Comment: @Gman: I agree with that, but i just wanted to fully understand it shortcomings, and how it was designed, only then i can better understand the reason behind the changes in C++0x. I want to get my basics right

Comment: @Gman - Shouldn't you have written `struct derived : public base {};`

Comment: @R Samuel: structs inherit publicly by default. It's the only other difference that have with classes, the other being structs default to `public:` while classes are `private:`.

Comment: @R Samuel: Oh, but yes I do need to at least inherit, don't I? :) Thanks, heh.

Answer (score 5):

The first one *is* a copy constructor, then second one is a templated constructor from `auto_ptr` with other template parameters.

The implementation has to provide a non-template copy constructor if it doesn't want the compiler generated one. This is because a templated constructor that could be used as a copy constructor doesn't suppress the compiler generate one and the compiler generated one would always be a better match for copy construction by virtue of not being a template.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking why a copy constructor is needed.  I think the OP is asking why there are _two_ things that both look like copy constructors.

Comment: @Omnifarious: And that's exactly what my answer addresses, why the non-template version must be supplied even if the template version appears to cover all options.